# Why is this JavaScript looping twice in Zapier?

Tags: javascript, zapier

Here is a [video](https://www.useloom.com/share/1a80d5621f7244b1acc36788c9aa60b3) that shows what I'm struggling with.

Here is a high level description of the process, followed by the actual JavaScript code I've written.

PROCESS
I built 2 Zaps that each run like this:

STEP 1 - Trigger (Cognito Form, which has repeating sections)

STEP 2 - JavaScript Code (which creates an Array of the form fields for ONE of the repeating sections, and separates them into individual strings using `.split`)

STEP 3 - Action (creates a ZOHO CRM Task for each string)

The first Zap runs on one of the sections of the form (Visits with Sales), and the second zap runs on a different section of the form (Visits without Sales). Each of these Zaps works fine on their own so I know the code is good, but I want to combine the two Zaps into one by combining the code.

I tried to combine by making five steps:

> Trigger - Code1 - Zoho1 - Code2 - Zoho2

but the Zoho2 Tasks were each repeated

I then tried to re-order the five steps:

> Trigger - Code1 - Code2 - Zoho1 - Zoho2

but now Zoho1 Tasks AND Zoho2 tasks were duplicated.

Finally I tried to combine ALL the JavaScript code into one:

> Tigger - CombinedCode1+2 - Zoho 1 - Zoho2

but only the strings from Arrays in "Code2" are available to me when I go to map them in Zoho1.

CODE:

```
if (inputData.stringVSAccount == null) {
  var listVSAccountArray = [];
  var listVSUnitsArray = [];
  var listVSPriceArray = [];
  var listVSNotesArray = [];
  var listVSVisitCallArray = [];
} else {
  var listVSAccountArray = inputData.stringVSAccount.split(",");
  var listVSUnitsArray = inputData.stringVSUnits.split(",");
  var listVSPriceArray = inputData.stringVSPrice.split(",");
  var listVSNotesArray = inputData.stringVSNotes.split(",");
  var listVSVisitCallArray = inputData.stringVSVisitCall.split(",");
}
var output = [];
var arrayNos = listVSAccountArray.length;
var i = 0;
do {
  var thisItemVSAccount = new String(listVSAccountArray[i]);
  var thisItemVSUnits = new String(listVSUnitsArray[i]);
  var thisItemVSPrice = new String(listVSPriceArray[i]);
  var thisItemVSNotes = new String(listVSNotesArray[i]);
  var thisItemVSVisitCall = new String(listVSVisitCallArray[i]);
  var thisItemObj = {};
  thisItemObj.itemVSAccount = thisItemVSAccount;
  thisItemObj.itemVSUnits = thisItemVSUnits;
  thisItemObj.itemVSPrice = thisItemVSPrice;
  thisItemObj.itemVSNotes = thisItemVSNotes;
  thisItemObj.itemVSVisitCall = thisItemVSVisitCall;
  output.push({ thisItemObj });
  i++;
} while (i < arrayNos);

//This is where the second zaps code is pasted in the combined version
if (inputData.stringOVAccount == null) {
  var listOVAccountArray = [];
  var listOVNotesArray = [];
  var listOVVisitCallArray = [];
} else {
  var listOVAccountArray = inputData.stringOVAccount.split(",");
  var listOVNotesArray = inputData.stringOVNotes.split(",");
  var listOVVisitCallArray = inputData.stringOVVisitCall.split(",");
}
var output = [];
var arrayNos = listOVAccountArray.length;
var i = 0;
do {
  var thisItemOVAccount = new String(listOVAccountArray[i]);
  var thisItemOVNotes = new String(listOVNotesArray[i]);
  var thisItemOVVisitCall = new String(listOVVisitCallArray[i]);
  var thisItemObj = {};
  thisItemObj.itemOVAccount = thisItemOVAccount;
  thisItemObj.itemOVNotes = thisItemOVNotes;
  thisItemObj.itemOVVisitCall = thisItemOVVisitCall;
  output.push({ thisItemObj });
  i++;
} while (i < arrayNos);
```

I just started learning JavaScript this week, and sense that I am missing something obvious, perhaps a set of brackets. Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. You're running into a confusing and largely undocumented feature where items after a code step run for each item returned. This is usually desired behavior - when you return 3 submissions you want to create 3 records.

In your case, it's also running subsequent unrelated actions multiple times, which sounds like it's undesired. In that case, it might be easier to have 2 zaps. Or, if "Zoho2" only ever happens once, put it first and let the branch happen downstream.

---

Separately, I've got some unsolicited javascript advice (since you mentioned you're a beginner). Check out `Array.forEach` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)), which will let you iterate through arrays without having to manage as many variables (your own `i` every time). Also, try to use `let` and `const` over `var` when possible - it keeps your variables scoped as small as possible so you don't accidentally leak values into other areas.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Thanks. Funny you should mention that it might be easier to have two zaps...I built two zaps originally, and they each run perfectly on their own. I thought it would be more elegant (and probably easier to maintain) a single combined zap, but that's when I started having this issue. I'll definitely read up on .forEach. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Just a note - you are declaring the same array variable `output` in both segments of your code block - the second declaration will be ignored.

Use the [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to iterate over your arrays, it will significantly cleanup you code. You also don't need to painstakingly construct the objects to be pushed into the `output` arrays.

This may not fix your issue but the code is far easier on the eye.

```
var listVSAccountArray = [],
    listVSUnitsArray = [],
    listVSPriceArray = [],
    listVSNotesArray = [],
    listVSVisitCallArray = [],
    output = [];

if (typeof inputData.stringVSAccount === 'string') {
  listVSAccountArray = inputData.stringVSAccount.split(',');
  listVSUnitsArray = inputData.stringVSUnits.split(',');
  listVSPriceArray = inputData.stringVSPrice.split(',');
  listVSNotesArray = inputData.stringVSNotes.split(',');
  listVSVisitCallArray = inputData.stringVSVisitCall.split(',');
}

// iterate over the array using forEach()
listVSAccountArray.forEach(function(elem, index){
  // elem is listVSAccountArray[index]
  output.push({
    itemVSAccount: elem,
    itemVSUnits: listVSUnitsArray[index],
    itemVSPrice: listVSPriceArray[index],
    itemVSNotes: listVSNotesArray[index],
    itemVSVisitCall: listVSVisitCallArray[index]
  })
})

//This is where the second zaps code is pasted in the combined version
var listOVAccountArray = [],
    listOVNotesArray = [],
    listOVVisitCallArray = [],
    output_two = []; // changed the name of the second output array

if (typeof inputData.stringOVAccount === 'string') {
  listOVAccountArray = inputData.stringOVAccount.split(',');
  listOVNotesArray = inputData.stringOVNotes.split(',');
  listOVVisitCallArray = inputData.stringOVVisitCall.split(',');
}

// iterate over the array using forEach()
listOVAccountArray.forEach(function(elem, index){
  // elem is listOVAccountArray[index]
  output_two.push({
    itemOVAccount: elem,
    itemOVNotes: listOVNotesArray[index],
    itemOVVisitCall: listOVVisitCallArray[index]
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Dan. I got another comment suggesting .forEach as well. I see what you mean about it cleaning up the code even if it doesn't solve this particular issue. I may end up needing to leave these as two separate zaps but am glad to have learned another function in any case. Thanks again